# MI HTML NO EJECUTA EL ARCHIVO DE JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Escribí el html con el nombre correcto de javascript y el archivo de javascript si lo ejecuto por separado funciona y no encuentro error dejo acá abajo el código de ambos por si existe algún error en javascript que haya pasado por alto lo único que hace el javascript es declarar arrays de un tamaño predeterminado y juntarlos en array mucho mas grande llamado fullMatriz

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <scripts src="ejecutarautomatica1.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
let inicio = [9]
inicio[0]= "PILOTOS";
inicio[1]= 01032019;
inicio[2]= 10042019;
inicio[3]= 11042019;
inicio[4]= 14042019;
inicio[5]= 20042019;
inicio[6]= 25042019;
inicio[7]= 07062019;
inicio[8]= 09062019;
;

let piloto1 = [9]
piloto1[0] = "jose   ";
piloto1[1] = 11042019;
piloto1[2] = 14042019;
piloto1[3] = 19042019;
piloto1[4] = 24052019;
piloto1[5] = 04062019;
piloto1[6] = 09072019;
piloto1[7] = 18072019;
piloto1[8] = 22072019;
;

let piloto2 = [9]
piloto2[0] = "daniel ";
piloto2[1] = 04042019;
piloto2[2] = 09042019;
piloto2[3] = 19052019;
piloto2[4] = 23052019;
piloto2[5] = 27052019;
piloto2[6] = 03062019;
piloto2[7] = 06062019;
piloto2[8] = 21072019;
;

//no tocar es la super matriz
let fullMatriz =[3]
fullMatriz[0] = inicio;
fullMatriz[1] = piloto1;
fullMatriz[2] = piloto2;

//el codigo que escribe la fullMatriz
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
    document.write(fullMatriz[i][j] + "------");
  }
  document.write("</br>");
}
```

Comment: Has puesto `<scripts ...>` en lugar de `<script ...>`, te sobra una S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error está en la línea de apertura de Javascript. Tienes puesto el PLURAL. Debes poner

```
<script
```

En lugar de

```
<scripts
```

Comment: gracias no lo había visto ahora me funciono

Comment: Por favor, si esta respuesta te ayudo a resolver el problema dala por respondida

Comment: Jakala, gracias por responder pero recuerda que preguntas con fallos tipograficos han de ser cerradas en vez de respondidas. indica el error en los comentarios bajo la pregunta. un saludo!

Comment: @lois6b perdona, desconocia esa norma. :(